# Emploi de « quelquefois », « parfois », « des fois »

Tags: usage, histoire, vocabulaire, standard

Pourquoi l'emploi de *des fois* est-il proscrit¹ et l'emploi de « quelquefois » ou « parfois » lui est préféré ?

Quel fait historique pousse néanmoins une partie de la population à utiliser *des fois* à tout va ?

—
<sup>1. « Pop. Des fois, s'emploie abusivement pour Parfois », [*Dictionnaire de l'Académie 9<sup>ème</sup> édition*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/fois)</sup>

Comment: Pour "au cas où" on pourrait préférer le mot toutefois

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*[Quelquefois](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quelquefois)* s'applique à un évènement discret, tandis que *[parfois](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parfois)* peut s'appliquer à un évènement discret (ponctuel) ou à un phénomène continu. « Il porte *parfois* une cravate », mais « je l'ai *quelquefois* vu porter une cravate » (*parfois* est possible mais moins courant). Lorsqu'il s'agit d'un évènement ponctuel, on peut aussi dire *quelques fois*¹ (rare) ou *des [fois](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois)*.

*Des fois* intervient dans plusieurs tournures, pour la plupart populaires (et non particulièrement familières²). Il peut être synonyme de *parfois* ou *quelquefois* ([TLF I.B.1.d.α](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois)). Il peut aussi signifier *au cas où* dans les locutions (elles aussi populaires) *si des fois* ([TLF I.B.1.d.β](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois))³ ou *des fois que* ([TLF I.D](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois)). *Des fois* peut s'employer dans des phrases où l'on contraste différentes occurrences ([TLF I.B.1.e](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois)) : « j'y pense *des fois*, et *d'autres fois* j'oublie » ; on peut aussi utiliser *quelquefois* ou *parfois* (« j'y pense parfois, et parfois j'oublie »), mais le contraste est moins appuyé (en particulier, *parfois* n'implique pas que les différentes circonstances soient incompatibles). L'Académie considère comme abusif beaucoup d'usages populaires, mais *des fois* n'a rien d'inapproprié même à l'écrit.

*Parfois* tend à supplanter *quelquefois* de nos jours (je n'avais pas remarqué ça en dehors de Ngram) ; *des fois*, qui est plus familier (donc plus oral) est peu présent dans le corpus (malgré les utilisations où il est le seul candidat).

[quelquefois,parfois,des fois http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=quelquefois%2Cparfois%2Cdes%20fois&corpus=7&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=quelquefois%2Cparfois%2Cdes+fois&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)

[quelques fois,plusieurs fois,des fois http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=quelques%20fois%2Cplusieurs%20fois%2Cdes%20fois&corpus=7&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=quelques+fois%2Cplusieurs+fois%2Cdes+fois&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)

¹ 
<sub>*Plusieurs fois* signifie un nombre de fois petit dans l'absolu. *Quelques fois*, *quelquefois* ou *parfois* peut signifier un nombre petit dans l'absolu, ou une faible proportion d'un grand nombre de fois ; la connotation de faible nombre est plus marquée que dans *plusieurs*. Quant à *des fois*, il désigne en général une faible proportion, mais c'est moins marqué.</sub>

² 
<sub>Un usage populaire est celui d'une partie de la population en général peu cultivée. Un usage familier est un usage que l'on n'utilise pas dans des circonstances formelles. Les deux notions se rejoignent souvent mais pas toujours.</sub>

³ 
<sub>Une variante régionale est *si toutefois*, qui plus conventionnellement signifie *à condition que* ([TLF D](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toutefois)).</sub>

---

[English summary]

*Quelquefois* qualifies a discrete event, while *parfois* can qualify either a discrete event or a continuous phenomenon. “*Il porte **parfois** une cravate*” (“he sometimes wears a tie”), but “*je l'ai **quelquefois** vu porter une cravate*”” (“I've occasionally seen him wear a tie”) (*parfois* is also possible but less common). For a discrete event, other possibilities include *quelques fois* (rare) or *des fois*.

*Des [fois](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois)* comes up in several idioms, usually colloquial but not particularly informal. It can be a synonym of *parfois* or *quelquefois* ([TLF I.B.1.d.α]). It can also mean *au cas où* (“in case [something happens]”) in the expressions *si des fois* (TLF I.B.1.d.β) and *des fois que* (TLF I.D). *Des fois* can be used in sentences where different occurrences of the event are contrasted (TLF I.B.1.e): « j'y pense **des fois**, et **d'autres fois** j'oublie* » (“Sometimes I remember, other times I forget”). While *quelquefois* or *parfois* can also be used, they mark less contrast (in particular *parfois* does not imply that the different circumstances are incompatible). The *Académie française* considers many popular idioms as invalid, but does not flag *des fois* as improper even in writing.

*Parfois* tends to supplant *quelquefois* nowadays (says Ngram, I hadn't noticed). *Des fois*, which tends to be less formal (and thus more common in spoken than written French), has few occurrences, despite the cases where it's the only possibility.

Answer (score 10):

*Des fois* relève du langage familier, tandis que *parfois* et *quelquefois* sont tout à fait corrects et peuvent être utilisés même dans des cas formels.

Ainsi, ces deux échanges sont d'un niveau correct :

> — Cela s'est-il déjà produit ?
>   — Oui, cela s'est produit quelques fois.
>
> — Cela se produit-il souvent ?
>   — Oui, cela se produit parfois, inopinément.
>
> — Cela se produit-il régulièrement ?
>   — Non, cela se produit quelquefois mais pas régulièrement.

Tandis que ceux qui suivent ont exactement le même sens, mais sont familiers :

> — C'est déjà arrivé ?
>   — C'est déjà arrivé plusieurs fois, oui.
>
> — Ça arrive souvent ?
>   — Des fois, oui, ça arrive sans prévenir.
>
> — Ça arrive régulièrement ?
>   — Non, des fois seulement.

*Des fois* permet également de signifier une hypothèse. Il n'en demeure pas moins familier :

> Tu es déjà prêt, des fois qu'ils arrivent en avance ?

signifie :

> Es-tu déjà prêt si quelquefois ils arrivaient en avance ?

*Des fois* serait plus récent que *parfois* et *quelquefois*. Sans en être certain, je suppose que la raison de son emploi est que *des* suivi de *fois* signifie *plusieurs fois*.

Plus d'infos sur *des fois*, *parfois* et *quelquefois* : [ici](http://discours.revues.org/3062).

Comment: Dans le premier exemple, pourquoi ne pas écrire « quelques fois » ?  On comprend ça plus que l'adverbe, *des fois* que ça porterait à confusion…

Comment: @Axioplase Tu as mille fois raison, j'ai corrigé! My bad.