# Orthographe de « quelque(s) fois »

Tags: orthographe, pluriel, accord

Une discussion intéressante a récemment eu lieu  [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/930/emploi-de-quelquefois-parfois-desfois) à propos de l'emploi de *des fois* à la place de *parfois* ou de *quelques fois*.

Je me demande pourquoi on utilise *quelques* au pluriel dans cette expression. Le *Grevisse*, §453 (8<sup>e</sup> edition) explique clairement que *quelque* doit s'accorder au nom dans ce cas puisqu'il est adjectif, mais comme *fois* est invariable cela ne répond pas au problème. D'un point de vue sémantique, les deux expressions *je vais au restaurant quelque fois* ou *je vais au restaurant quelques fois* me semblent correctes, selon que l'on veuille considérer que l'accent est porté par l'idée de répétition (au cas où *fois* serait pluriel) ou par l'action même, cas où je dirais que le singulier serait plus approprié en raison du fait que chaque fois (et non pas « *chaques fois »…) qu'on va au restaurant c'est une occasion séparée, indépendante. Il me semble pourtant que l'usage établi est toujours pluriel et je m'en demande la raison.

Answer (score 5):

***Quelque*** est un adjectif indéfini, désignant un ou plusieurs parmi d'autres. *Il s'accorde donc* : « Trouvez-vous quelque autre explication ? », ou : « quelqu'autre », bien que des puristes n'admettent l'élision que pour « *un(e)* quelqu'autre » ; « J'ai visité quelques musées ».

« Je vais au restaurant quelque fois » me gêne donc ; il faudrait un fait *unique* : « Quelque fois qu'un malheur m'arrivât, vous trouveriez mon testament chez mon notaire, M<sup>e</sup> de la Basoche » ; « Désirez-vous quelque fauteuil plus confortable ? ».

Donc, sauf en ce dernier cas particulier, « quelques fois » ou « quelquefois » en un mot, qui signifie cependant plutôt « de fois à autre », « de temps à autre ».

***Fois*** n'est pas la marque du pluriel, en ce sens il est invariable, mais peut être singulier ou pluriel : « Il était une fois … », « Toutes les fois que … ».

Comment: Merci, je suis bien d'accord qu'il faut faire l'accord et même que mon expression "_fois_ est invariable" est peu correcte, et qu'il aurait fallu dire que _fois_ manque de marque du pluriel. Pourtant, je reste confus sur l'usage de _quelque fois_ qui, quoique peu usité, ne me semblerait pas abhorrant.

Comment: @ Filippo Alberto Edoardo L'usage de "quelque fois" est légitime dans une expression comme : "Emportez un bidon de secours, si quelque fois vous tombiez en panne d'essence" : le cas peut ne pas être tout à fait unique dans une vie, mais il est rare. Pour : "... si vous tombez quelquefois en panne ..." signifierait que vous êtes assez coutumier de cette distraction.