# Écrit-on « quelque soit » ou « quel que soit » ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, conjonctions

J'orthographie naturellement :

> On souhaite rencontrer ces personnes, **quelque soit** l'endroit où elles se trouvent.

Le correcteur orthographique embarqué tique un peu, indique qu'il y a "Confusion" et suggère :

> On souhaite rencontrer ces personnes, **quel que** soit l'endroit où elles se trouvent.

De quel genre de confusion ces deux graphies sont-elles la source ?

---

Question apparentée : *[orthographe de quelque fois](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7879/orthographe-de-quelques-fois)*

Comment: Je ne suis pas certain de bien comprendre. Te demandes-tu si les deux orthographes ont des sens différents ? Si c’est le cas, je pense que non car seul « quel que soit » est correct et que ton correcteur te signale *ta* confusion.

Comment: [« quelque » ou « quel que » ?](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/quelque-ou-quel-que)

Comment: @laure Il me semble que votre avis sur cette question http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/584/french-language-francophonie serait intéressant.

Answer (score 7):

En fait "quelque soit" ne peut pas exister devant un verbe conjugué. 
"Quelque" n'est pas un mot pouvant se poser comme un sujet seul car c'est un adjectif indéfini.

Tu pourrais l'utiliser dans ce bout de phrase en transformant la phrase de la sorte : "en quelque endroit que ce soit"
Là, "quelque" qualifie le nom "endroit" et signifie "n'importe quel endroit"

Et là, PAF ! En transformant la phrase, tu t'aperçois que le véritable sujet du verbe "soit" est le nom commun "endroit" donc :

1. tu ne peux pas employer "quelque" car ce n'est pas un pronom qui
   peut remplacer un nom.
2. Du coup, l'autre tournure, "quel"    représente le sujet
       "endroit"    et agit donc comme pronom et précède    donc un verbe
       conjugué et    tout s'accorde avec le sujet d'origine. Exemples divers :

"Quel que soit l'endroit ..."
"Quels que soient les dangers..."
"Quelle que soit la place..."

Comment: Que signifie PAF ? D'après http://www.wordreference.com/fren/paf, une acception est paysage audiovisuel français et une autre est plus charnelle, mais ces deux ne s'appliquent pas ici ?

Comment: C'est une onomatopée exprimant ici un claquement de la main signalant qu'on a trouvé.  http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/paf

Comment: Désolé pour l'onomatopée...

Comment: Un peu d'esprit de contradiction: _je doute que_ quelque soit _toujours interdit comme sujet_.

Comment: "Quelque soit" ne peut pas être sujet à mon avis. La tournure n'existe pas il me semble ;)

Answer (score 4):

Du *[site](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/quelque-ou-quel-que)* indiqué par Laure, les exemples qui ont dessillé mes yeux :

*Devant un adjectif, un nom ou un adverbe*

> - **Quelque** souriant qu’il semble, il est malheureux.
> - Je n’en ai parlé qu’à **quelques** personnes.
> - **Quelque** rapidement qu’il coure, je le rattraperai.

*En revanche, si le terme qui pose problème est placé devant un verbe (qui peut être précédé de « en ») ou un pronom personnel comme « il(s) » ou « elle(s) », il faut écrire « quel que », en deux mots, et accorder « quel » avec le sujet du verbe en question :*

> - L’examinateur n’accepte aucun retard, **quelle qu’en** *soit* la raison. (verbe)
> - **Quels que** *soient* vos problèmes, ils ont certainement une solution. (verbe)
> - Présentez une pièce d’identité, **quelle qu**’*elle* soit. (pronom personnel)

La règle du subjonctif :

*Qu’il s’écrive en deux mots (« quel(s)… que ») ou en un seul, le « quelque(s) » qui marque une opposition est toujours suivi d’un* verbe au subjonctif :

> - *Quel qu’il* soit, *il faudra qu’il se montre*.
> - *Quelque intelligent qu’il* paraisse, *il a échoué*.
> - *Quelques efforts qu’il* fasse, *il n’y parviendra pas.*

N.B. : Même si l'on entend parfois *Quelqu'intelligent qu'il soit*, l'élision est une erreur, il faut prononcer entièrement le *quelque* suivi du mot commençant par une voyelle.